# Jquery interface Sortable on update submit change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery sortable script

```
$("#visuals").sortable({
  revert:200,
  opacity:.8,
  tolerance:"pointer",
  placeholder:"dropZone",
  start:function(event,ui){
    ui.placeholder.html("<div><div></div></div>");
}}).disableSelection()
```

I would like to create a "on update" function to get the original indexed position and find the updated indexed position.

Something like this:

```
update:function(event,ui){
  previous=$("originalElement").prevAll().length+1
  updated=$("updatedElement").prevAll().length+1
}
```

original:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

updated moving item 3 to item 1 spot:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

would return:

```
original index: 3
updated index: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Original index and updated index can be obtained like this:

```
  start:function(event,ui){
    originalIndex=ui.item.prevAll().length+1
  },
  update:function(event,ui){
    updatedIndex=ui.item.prevAll().length+1
  }
```